# Jenkins environment variables for Maven pom dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, environment-variables, pom.xml

We have several jobs on jenkins that are running on hierarchical dependencies on each other.

Lets say, Job2 has a dependencies on the Job1 for the pom.xml version.
so whenever we have changes at the end of sprint for Job1, we are in need to change the versions of the pom on the dependencies inside the Job2 before releasing the artifacts at the end of sprint, so this might not handy if we have Job3, Job4, Job5 that are depending on the version of Job1. we need to change all the version of Job1 on all the pom.xml of all the Jobs that is dependent on it.

So the question, are there any ways to solve this, probably using jenkins env variables? need a helping hand how to perform it based on the issues above.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using SNAPSHOT's ?

Comment: Are your jobs releasing the maven artifacts and you need to reference the latest release version in the downstream release build?

Comment: @khmarbaise during the development, we use -snapshot on the version of the dependencies, but when we need to release the artifacts at the end of sprint, we need to exclude the word snapshot on the version indicating that we will will use the release version of the dependencies, because of naming convention on our release artifacts are just version number no -release word on it.

Comment: @Ralf yes, specifically the latest release version of the dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed exceptions / if else condition on deleting word on xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615981/sed-exceptions-if-else-condition-on-deleting-word-on-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have dependencies amongst your internally developed artifacts. During development you want to depend on the latest snapshot of those artifacts, but a release build shall depend on the latest release version of those same artifacts.

This can be achieved with Jenkins and Maven. Set up your release build job like so:

1. Add a "Pre Step" section of type "Invoke top level Maven targets". In this step you run the targets `versions:update-properties scm:checkin` to update your internal dependencies to point to the latest release version.
2. In the main build step do the release: `release:prepare release:perform -B`. This builds the release version, increments the version number to the next snapshot version, builds that next snapshot version and checks this back into scm.
3. In a "Post Step" run the targets of the Pre Step again (with `allowSnapshots=true`) to update your dependencies to reference the latest snapshot version.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE: For this to work all jobs have to hit the same Maven repository. Locally on the Jenkins server or your corporate Nexus.

Comment: I dont understand these, how will the pom version of the other Jobs will get the pom version of the Job1

Comment: Maven will know because the new versions are installed locally and optionally deployed to your company repository, e.g. Nexus. I will add a note that all jobs have to hit the same Maven repository for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jenkins [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) for passing variables to the downstream projects. Plugin wiki got detailed explanation.

Comment: seems like this is only for triggering builds that are dependents on Job1, but does this have environment variables for the pom versions dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have the required version at the end of execution of Job1, export it as environment variable or store it in some of the file on build server like

```
pom_version=1.1
```

Now when triggering all the downstream jobs, set the parameter of jobs as "pom_version" and either pass this file to pick the required key/value or set the value in pre-defined parameter.

[image]

After that, make sure all of your downstream jobs are configured as parameterized with parameter "pom_version"