# sed exceptions / if else condition on deleting word on xml

Tags: xml, linux, shell, jenkins, sed

I am currently using a sed script:

cd (root folder) first

```
find . -name pom.xml | xargs sed -i "/<dependencies>/,/'<\/dependencies>'/s/-SNAPSHOT//"
```

currently, this script removes the `-SNAPSHOT` on all `pom.xml` on a folder including its subfolders, under the tagging `<dependencies></dependencies>`, 
example of xml is:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

    <artifactId>scheduler-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Scheduler Service Web Application</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.infor.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>scheduler-service-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.security.authentication</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth10a-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.26-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

so now, what I need is to exclude those tagging which has word "scheduler-service-core" or basically scheduler, as I dont need to parse this, but my script is removing it because it is under dependencies tagging, How can I have exclusion on this one? the words "scheduler" will be changing because I will be using this on different services, so the script should be relying the exclusion on the word as I will change it when using to different services.

desired output should be:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

    <artifactId>scheduler-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Scheduler Service Web Application</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.infor.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>scheduler-service-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.security.authentication</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth10a-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.26</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

if you can see, the `-SNAPSHOT` for `artifactID - scheduler-service-core` has been retained, and all other dependencies below which has `-SNAPSHOT` will be removed.

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: hi @Cyrus I have edited the post

Comment: when I try your command I obtain `sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command"`

Comment: you should cd on the root folder first i think,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to edit XML with `sed`, it isn't made for this kind of structured data. `sed` scripts that edit XML invariably break down when someone inserts benign whitespaces somewhere you didn't originally expect them, and nobody who edits XML expects things to break because of layout changes.

Instead, I'd use XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Identity template: just copy everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special rule for version tags that include -SNAPSHOT and whose
       parent tag has an artifactId subtag that contains scheduler-service -->
  <xsl:template match="//version[contains(., '-SNAPSHOT') and not(contains(../artifactId, 'scheduler-service'))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- copy attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!-- and only use the part of the node content before -SNAPSHOT -->
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-SNAPSHOT')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you can use e.g.

```
xsltproc foobar.xsl pom.xml
```

or

```
xalan -in pom.xml -xsl foobar.xsl
```

depending on which XSLT processor you like, where foobar.xsl contains the above stylesheet.

Comment: nice answer!!! maybe the xpath should take only into account the versions under `dependency`, anyway +1!

Comment: will this work on jenkins? I will execute script on Jenkins, after this, I will git push it to the gitlab repo

Comment: @NeilyoungGuce why do you keep asking that instead of just trying it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, jenkins can run any sort of shell command, so as long as xsltproc or xalan are installed on the jenkins server, it shouldn't be a problem. Note that to edit the file in-place, you'll need an extra bit of scripting, as in `xsltproc foobar.xsl pom.xml > pom.xml.new && mv pom.xml.new pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

By using `XSLT` technologies:

**STYLESHEET:**

```
$ more pomConvertor.xslt 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- default behavior is to copy everything nodes and attribute-->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- when you reach version node under dependency for which the artifactId does contain scheduler you copy the string before -SNAPSHOT -->
    <xsl:template match="//dependencies/dependency/version[not(contains(../artifactId/text(),'scheduler'))]">
        <version><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text(),'-')"/></version>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**INPUT:**

```
$ more pom.xml 
<pom>
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

    <artifactId>scheduler-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Scheduler Service Web Application</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.infor.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>scheduler-service-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.security.authentication</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth10a-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.26-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</pom>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ xsltproc pomConvertor.xslt pom.xml                                                                                             
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pom>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>scheduler-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Scheduler Service Web Application</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.infor.techstack.scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>scheduler-service-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.security.authentication</groupId>
      <artifactId>oauth10a-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.26</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</pom>
```

Comment: will this work on jenkins? I will execute script on Jenkins, after this, I will git push it to the gitlab repo.

Comment: @Neilyoung Guce: as long as you redirect the stdout to a new pom file and replace the previous pom file by this new one then it should be fine I think

Comment: so this process doesnt parse or modified the existing pom.xml?